# Hot skip special character in txt file python

Tags: python, character, skip

I have some issues while reading txt files. What i have to do is read files ( about 360 ) and make a plot. Everything works except when there is a special character in my file such us: "". When my reading function finds that character it crashes. Is there any way to skip it? My code:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

i = 10
j = 0
X = []
Y = []
Z = []
k = 0
A = np.zeros([360,719])

for i in range(10,360,10):
        X = []
        Y = []
        if len(str(i)) == 2:
            data = open(dir + '\\150317_ScPONd_0%s_radio.txt'%i, 'r')
        else:
            data = open(dir + '\\150317_ScPONd_%s_radio.txt'%i, 'r')
        z = data.readlines()
        data.close()
        for line in z:
            if not line.startswith('$'):
                data_2 = line.split('\t')
                X.append(data_2[0])
                Y.append(data_2[1])
        A[j,:] = X
        A[(j+1),:] = Y
```

And here is how my file looks like:
[image]
Is there any way to skip those "$" lines? Sorry for that picture, I have no idea how to attache It better.

Comment: Why not use np.genfromtxt?

Comment: have you tried `if line.startswith('$')==False:`?

Comment: @WhatsThePoint yes I've tried but it failed.

Comment: @user1753919 thank You very much it works! I did not even know such reading option as genfromtxt.

Answer (score 0):

Thaks to @user1753919 I have found an answer. If someone would be still interested in this, here is working code:

```
for i in range(10,360,10):
        X = []
        Y = []
        if len(str(i)) == 2:
            data = np.genfromtxt(dir + '\\150317_ScPONd_0%s_radio.txt'%i,skip_header = 12)
        else:
            data = np.genfromtxt(dir + '\\150317_ScPONd_%s_radio.txt'%i,skip_header = 12)
        for line in data:
            X.append(line[0])
            Y.append(line[1])
        A[j,:] = X
        A[(j+1),:] = Y
        plt.plot(A[j,:],A[(j+1),:],label = '{} K'.format(i))
        plt.hold
        j = j+2
```

Answer (score 0):

`genfromtxt` is overkill.

```
np.loadtxt(file, comments='$')
```